# How do I define a notion of infinite coproducts for objects in a category?

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, type-theory, lambda-calculus

As part of a project I'm working on; I am writing an interpreter for the STLC (simply typed $\lambda$-calculus) in which the type-checking algorithm treats isomorphic types as "equal".
I know that Cartesian closed categories serve as a model for the STLC.
My category theory is rather sketchy nonetheless I had the idea that I can do something with this.

Let us say I wish to construct from $\mathcal{C}$ a new category $S(\mathcal{C})$ in which objects somehow denote isomorphism classes of objects in $\mathcal{C}$ and morphisms denote  morhpisms between these isomorphism classes.

My idea is to represent this isomorphism class using coproducts. So if $A \cong B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ then we have an object $A+B$ in $S(\mathcal{C})$. This seems to work out fine for finite coproducts. However, there is no gurantee that the isomorphism classes would be finite.

So what I would like to do is to *generalise* the coproduct to a family of objects. In particular, if I had two objects I would have the following diagram commute :

[image: Coproduct of two objects]

For any arbitrary family of objects $A_i$ indexed by $i \in I$ I need a similar diagram to commute :

[image: Coproduct of any objects]

This diagram must commute for all $i \in I$.

Here I am denoting the coproduct  over $I$ as $\sum_{i \in I}A_i$ and the injections are labelled $\kappa_i$.

Is my approach correct?

I have a feeling the answer is yes but I am not sure how rigourous this is. How do I prove that the object $\sum_{i \in I}A_i$ defined as the object for whom *all* such diagrams commute is even well-defined?

Comment: Have you heard of the skeleton of a category? The skeleton $Sk(C)$ of a category $C$ is a category equivalent to $C$ such that, for $a , b \in Sk(C)$, if $a \cong b$, then $a = b$. (That is, isomorphic objects are equal)

Comment: Yes. Can I define a functor from $C$ to $Sk(C)$ that maps any object from $C$ to it's isomorphic "representative"? The arrows could also work; I have a feeling it is possible to define such a functor.

Comment: The two categories are equivalent, so yes of course there is such a functor